# Vector magnitude subtraction

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Please help! This was in a textbook and I cannot seem to make sense of it. Would it not be 2?

The two vectors **a** and **b** are perpendicular. If **a** has magnitude 8 and **b** has magnitude 3, what is  |a−2b|??

I

Comment: what is the dimension of   vector ? how many coordinates  it    has

Comment: see please my answer

Comment: $\mathbf a-\mathbf b$ forms the third side of a right triangle; $\mathbf a-2\mathbf b$ also forms the hypotenuse of a right triangle. What are the lengths of its other two sides?

Answer (score 0):

i will use brute force method let us suppose we have following vector

$a=[{\sqrt{64},0,0}]$

$b=[ 0,  \sqrt{9}, 0]$

they are  orthogonal  $a*b=0$

now  $a-2*b=[ \sqrt(64),  -2*\sqrt{9}, 0]$

length of this will be  $\sqrt{64+4*9+0}$

which is equal to $\sqrt{100}=10$

Answer (score 0):

Since your vectors are perpendicular, they don't directly add and subtract like scalars would. 
Denoting them in **R**$^2$:

$\textbf{a} - 2\textbf{b} = \begin{pmatrix}
8 \\
0
\end{pmatrix} - 
2 \begin{pmatrix}
0 \\
3
\end{pmatrix} = 
\begin{pmatrix}
8 \\
-6
\end{pmatrix}.$

Thus we need to consider what the value of $\begin{pmatrix}
8 \\
-6
\end{pmatrix}$.

Often, this is calculated with the Euclidean Distance, as $\left| \begin{pmatrix}
8 \\
-6
\end{pmatrix} \right| = \sqrt{8^2 + (-6)^2} = 10. $